# SSH file move with PowerShell

Tags: macos, powershell, ssh

I'm having problems accessing the shared folders of a Mac from which I need to download some files due to a series of bugs in Catalina.
After involving some experts we agreed that the only way to get those files is via SSH.

I have NEVER used SSH so I ask you IT wizards: can anyone tell me how to connect to a Mac via SSH from a PowerShell script (it works perfectly with PuTTY) and MOVE all the files that have the name made like this `??????????????????-202???????????.csv` from the Mac download folder to a local folder?

Put simply I need the SSH equivalent of the statement

```
move \\serverpath\downloads\?????????????????????-202????????????.csv c:\mylocalpath
```

I'm ONLY interested in those files, the other files must remain where they are.
As already mentioned, I did some tests with PuTTY, I can list the files that interest me but now I need these files to be moved automatically by a scheduled operation.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell doesn't natively issue SSH commands.

You'll need either to invoke an ssh utility locally (just like invoking any other native command or executable with all the command line stuff) from PowerShell, or else (my preference) use a module that will do the translation to SSH for you.

I have never used the module [Posh-SSH](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Posh-SSH/3.1.3), but with 31M downloads, it's probably worth trying. Docs are [on GitHub](https://github.com/darkoperator/Posh-SSH)

Comment: openssh was already a built-in component of Windows some years ago

Comment: I was thinking of starting Putty with the -m parameter from my Powershell script.
With the -m parameter you can run a command script but I've never tried anything like this.
Does anyone know how to help me?

Comment: Also OpenSSH seems to be a good choice but I need the command to move the files. My problem is this! After I found the command I can find the way to use it but I must find it before!

Answer (score 0):

After a little research with my friends I found a valid solution.
Now I use WinSCP to connect to the damaged Mac, get the files i need, delete them and close the session just in one line:

```
PS C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP> .\winscp.com /command "open sftp://username:password@10.0.6.91/" "cd downloads" "get ??????????????????-202???????????.csv C:\ClientCSV\ -delete" "exit"
```

Hope this can be useful for someone else. Thank you everyone